# Checkbox shows hidden field - not working onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, hide, show

I am using this probably ugly javascript to show a text box (in a li tag plus its label) if a checkbox is checked.

```
   $("#li-2-21").css("display","none");
   $("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").click(function(){
    if ($("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#li-2-21").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {     
        $("#li-2-21").hide("fast");
    }
  });
```

That works fine but it doesn't work if a page is loaded and the checkbox is already checked because the #li-2-21 gets automatically hidden.

Do I need to create a function that reads the state of the checkbox? Or is there a simpler way?

Oh and also feel free to shorten that ugly code, I guess there's a shorter way to achieve my goal?
Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most concisely:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").change(function() {
      $("#li-2-21")[$(this).is(":checked") ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast")
  }).change();
});
```

EDIT : switched from click to change event

Comment: looks nice but doesn't do anything when you click the checkbox?

Comment: why not ? the event hander is set up upon page load so it'll toggle visibility thereafter .. 

At page load we bind checkbox click to a function that shows/hides a listitem according to the checkbox state . we also FIRE (via click()) that event handler once so that it sets the display css correctly at the beginning

i was missing a paren - maybe you didn't catch that .. i've edited

Comment: Nearly perfect. Now onload the text field is hidden but the checkbox is checked.
And if I set the checkbox to be checked in html, onload the text field appears but the checkbox gets unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your click function into a separate function (not inline) and run it on the load of the page:

```
function ToggleCheckbox() {
    if ($("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#li-2-21").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {     
        $("#li-2-21").hide("fast");
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").click(ToggleCheckbox);
    ToggleCheckBox(); 
});
```

If you want to clean it up a bit I'd extract the checkbox and languages element into separate vars:

```
var languages = $("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8");
var checkbox = $("#li-2-21");
```

make sure you place them in the appropriate scope though. This will mean that jQuery doesn't need to keep requerying the DOM to find them.

Comment: This looks very elaborate and works but the text field isn't hidden onload if the checkbox is unchecked. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: have edited answer. I should have been more specific, in that, the toggle call and the click assignment need to happen once the document is ready. The `$(function() { });` call will make sure that happens.

Comment: Sorry I'm really bad at JS but this still doesn't hide the text field onload if checkbox is unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function immediately upon defining it's function. Example:

```
   $("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").click(function(){
    if ($("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#li-2-21").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {     
        $("#li-2-21").hide("fast");
    }
  }).click();
```