# Show field if certain option value is selected - must work on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, show

This [genius code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580276/checkbox-shows-hidden-field-not-working-onload) works fine for checkboxes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Languages-spoken-and-understood-8").change(function() {
      $("#li-2-21")[$(this).is(":checked") ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast")
  }).change();
});
```

What I love about is that it works onload.

I was trying to modify it for a select box. Code is autogenerated by cforms on wordpress.

```
<select name="Severity-of-your-symptoms" id="Severity-of-your-symptoms" class="cformselect" >
    <option value="full01_severity_notselected" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
    <option value="Mild">Mild</option>
    <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
    <option value="Severe">Severe</option>
    <option value="full01_severity_other">Other</option>
</select>
```

This is what I tried:

```
  $('#Severity-of-your-symptoms').change(function() {
    $("#li-10-14")[("#Severity-of-your-symptoms[value='full01_severity_other']").attr('selected', 'selected') ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast")
  });change();
```

Obviously it's not working. Only if "Other" is selected, the text box should appear.
Is there a way to use that nifty code again somehow or do I need a bigger function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, this would be a much shorter way of doing it:

```
$('#Severity-of-your-symptoms').change(function() {
  $("#li-10-14")[$(this).val() == "full01_severity_other" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
}).change();
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/q5kKz/).

When getting or setting the value of a `<select>` (or any other input type element) you can use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).  In case anyone wants this *without* the animation, it'd look like this:

```
$('#Severity-of-your-symptoms').change(function() {
  $("#li-10-14").toggle($(this).val() == "full01_severity_other");
}).change();
```