# Show/Hide Field Based on Option Value in Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use a slightly modified version of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580886/show-field-if-certain-option-value-is-selected-must-work-on-pageload) to show/hide the field Return Time on [this page](http://www.karmajets.com/quote/) based on Type of Trip:

One Way:  Return Time is hidden

Round Trip:  Return Time is shown

Here is the Select Box html.  Code is autogenerated by cforms on wordpress.

```
<select name="TripType" id="TripType" class="cformselect" >
                <option value="One Way">One Way</option>
                <option value="Round Trip">Round Trip</option>
            </select>
```

And here is the form element I'm trying to hide:

```
<li id="li--8" class=""><label id="label--8" for="DepartLeg2-Time"><span>Return Time</span></label><select name="DepartLeg2-Time" id="DepartLeg2-Time" class="cformselect" >
                    <option value="12:00am">12:00am</option>
                    <option value="12:30am">12:30am</option>
                    <option value="1:00am">1:00am</option>
                    <option value="1:30am">1:30am</option>
                    <option value="2:00am">2:00am</option>
                    <option value="2:30am">2:30am</option>
                    <option value="3:00am">3:00am</option>
                    <option value="3:30am">3:30am</option>
                    <option value="4:00am">4:00am</option>
                    <option value="4:30am">4:30am</option>
                    <option value="5:00am">5:00am</option>
                    <option value="5:30am">5:30am</option>
                    <option value="6:00am">6:00am</option>
                    <option value="6:30am">6:30am</option>
                    <option value="7:00am">7:00am</option>
                    <option value="7:30am">7:30am</option>
                    <option value="8:00am">8:00am</option>
                    <option value="8:30am">8:30am</option>
                    <option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
                    <option value="9:30am">9:30am</option>
                    <option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
                    <option value="10:30am">10:30am</option>
                    <option value="11:00am">11:00am</option>
                    <option value="11:30am">11:30am</option>
                    <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
                    <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
                    <option value="1:00pm">1:00pm</option>
                    <option value="1:30pm">1:30pm</option>
                    <option value="2:00pm">2:00pm</option>
                    <option value="2:30pm">2:30pm</option>
                    <option value="3:00pm">3:00pm</option>
                    <option value="3:30pm">3:30pm</option>
                    <option value="4:00pm">4:00pm</option>
                    <option value="4:30pm">4:30pm</option>
                    <option value="5:00pm">5:00pm</option>
                    <option value="5:30pm">5:30pm</option>
                    <option value="6:00pm">6:00pm</option>
                    <option value="6:30pm">6:30pm</option>
                    <option value="7:00pm">7:00pm</option>
                    <option value="7:30pm">7:30pm</option>
                    <option value="8:00pm">8:00pm</option>
                    <option value="8:30pm">8:30pm</option>
                    <option value="9:00pm">9:00pm</option>
                    <option value="9:30pm">9:30pm</option>
                    <option value="10:00pm">10:00pm</option>
                    <option value="10:30pm">10:30pm</option>
                    <option value="11:00pm">11:00pm</option>
                    <option value="11:30pm">11:30pm</option>
                </select></li>
```

Here is the javascript I'm using:

```
$("#TripType").change(function() {
  $("#li--8")[$(this).val() == "Round Trip" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
}).change();
```

I have the code working here on JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/MS4Ck/. However, it is not working on the site.  My console is not giving me any errors except for a reference error coming from some logging code I put in there to make sure the javascript is being called (it is).  Any ideas?  Thank you so much!

Comment: If the logging code is in JavaScript that could prevent the execution of the rest of your code. I don't know what else would cause the code to fail on your site but not on jsfiddle...

Comment: So you simply want to hide the form?

Comment: try to debug the process using some debugging tool in browser like firebug..see what happens on select index change event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but make sure this function is wrapped in a docReady function eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TripType").change(function() {
        $("#li--8")[$(this).val() == "Round Trip" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much Sdedelbrock! You rock!

Comment: Also, could you tell me how to add another element in addition to li--8?  Like if I wanted to add li--7 as well?

Comment: Thanks so much!  I knew it was something close to that, but I didn't have the quotes and commas arranged correctly.  Thank you so much again for your help!  I really appreciate it.