# Show and hide form fields (li) dependant on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, checkbox, show-hide

I have an output form (using cforms in Wordpress) and I want to show a further text box depending on whether the check box is checked.

E.g. Are you an agent? (Yes/No). If yes (checked) reveal 'please enter your number'.

```
    <ol class="cf-ol">
        <li id="li--5" class=""><label for="cf_field_5"><span>Phone</span></label><input name="cf_field_5" id="cf_field_5" class="single fldrequired" value="" type="text"><span class="reqtxt">(required)</span></li>
        <li id="li--6" class=""><label for="cf_field_6" class="cf-before"><span>Are you an agent?</span></label><input name="cf_field_6" id="cf_field_6" class="cf-box-b" type="checkbox"></li>
        <li id="li--7" class=""><label for="cf_field_7"><span>Please provide your agent number</span></label><input name="cf_field_7" id="cf_field_7" class="single" value="" type="text"></li>
        <li id="li--8" class=""><label for="cf_field_8" class="cf-before"><span>Are you a policy owner</span></label><input name="cf_field_8" id="cf_field_8" class="cf-box-b" type="checkbox"></li>
        <li id="li--9" class=""><label for="cf_field_9"><span>Please provide the last 4 digits from your social security number</span></label><input name="cf_field_9" id="cf_field_9" class="single" value="" type="text"></li>
        <li id="li--10" class=""><label for="cf_field_10"><span>Policy number (if known)</span></label><input name="cf_field_10" id="cf_field_10" class="single" value="" type="text"></li>
        <li id="li--11" class=""><label for="cf_field_11"><span>Message</span></label><textarea cols="30" rows="8" name="cf_field_11" id="cf_field_11" class="area"></textarea></li>
    </ol>
```

It's been a long day and I'm really struggling to get this to work! I've tried to use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580276/checkbox-shows-hidden-field-not-working-onload) but failing!

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Show what text-input in response to checking which checkbox? Can you show only the minimal code required to produce a minimal test-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a click callback to the checkbox, have the number input hidden by default, toggle the input on click:

Similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/seibert_cody/7agdf65p/ ?

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <label for="cf_field_7">
            <span>Please provide your agent number</span>
        </label>
        <input name="cf_field_6" id="cf_field_6" class="cf-box-b" type="checkbox">

        <ol id="agent_number_sub_list" type="a">
            <li>
                <label for="cf_field_7">
                    <span>Please provide your agent number</span>
                </label>
                <input name="cf_field_7" id="cf_field_7" class="single" value="" type="text">
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
#agent_number_sub_list{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cf_field_6").click(function(){
        $("#agent_number_sub_list").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This did the job exactly without the need to change the output. I didn't use the agent_number_sub_list but stuck with the existing IDs. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your HTML to hide the `li` by default:

```
<ol class="cf-ol">
    <li id="li--5" class=""><label for="cf_field_5"><span>Phone</span></label><input name="cf_field_5" id="cf_field_5" class="single fldrequired" value="" type="text"><span class="reqtxt">(required)</span></li>
    <li id="li--6" class=""><label for="cf_field_6" class="cf-before"><span>Are you an agent?</span></label><input name="cf_field_6" id="cf_field_6" class="cf-box-b" type="checkbox"></li>
    <li id="li--7" style="display: none"><label for="cf_field_7"><span>Please provide your agent number</span></label><input name="cf_field_7" id="cf_field_7" class="single" value="" type="text"></li>
    <li id="li--8" class=""><label for="cf_field_8" class="cf-before"><span>Are you a policy owner</span></label><input name="cf_field_8" id="cf_field_8" class="cf-box-b" type="checkbox"></li>
    <li id="li--9" class=""><label for="cf_field_9"><span>Please provide the last 4 digits from your social security number</span></label><input name="cf_field_9" id="cf_field_9" class="single" value="" type="text"></li>
    <li id="li--10" class=""><label for="cf_field_10"><span>Policy number (if known)</span></label><input name="cf_field_10" id="cf_field_10" class="single" value="" type="text"></li>
    <li id="li--11" class=""><label for="cf_field_11"><span>Message</span></label><textarea cols="30" rows="8" name="cf_field_11" id="cf_field_11" class="area"></textarea></li>
</ol>
```

Then add JavaScript to hide/show the LI as the checkbox is checked/unchecked:

```
(function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("cf_field_6").onclick = function () {

            document.getElementById("li--7").style.display = this.checked ?
                null :
            "none";

        };
    };
})();
```

Here's the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/e8sqk1h4/

If you have JQuery available, then the JavaScript becomes a little simpler:

```
$(function () {
    $("#cf_field_6").click(function () {
        $("#li--7").css("display", this.checked ? "" : "none");
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/axt6kcc9/1/

**Note:** You would use *either* of the above-given JavaScript, not both. I would also note that your `id` tags aren't very descriptive, but that's your choice.